# Calculate daily avg/total user duration that spans over 2 days?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where it stores all a user's login and logout dates and the number of hours a user has spent on the platform.

With that, I want to calculate:

1. The daily average duration of a user on the platform
2. The daily sum of all users' duration on platform

This is a MySQL query that I have begun to construct:

```
SELECT 
    date(login_datetime)        as "Login Date"
    round(avg(hourslapsed),0)   as "Avg Daily Hours", 
    sum(hourslapsed)            as "Total Daily Hours"
FROM lapsed_table
GROUP BY "Login Date"
```

This is an example of lapsed_table I currently have:

```
id  date(login_datetime)    login_datetime      logout_datetime     timestampdiff(hour, login_datetime, logout_datetime) as "hourslapsed"
--  --------------------    --------------      ---------------     ----------------------------------------------------
1   Oct 1                   Oct 1 10 am         Oct 4 5pm             79
2   Oct 3                   Oct 3 11pm          Oct 5 1am             26
```

The above query was constructed under the assumptions that users will not be spending over 24 hours on the platform, and in the rare case they do, it will not be wildly over 24 hours and so I did a GROUP BY "Login Date". Durations that span over two different dates (i.e. Wed 11pm to Thu 2am --> Wed 3 hours) are also counted under the login date.

HOWEVER, this is a problem because users have left the platform running without logging off, thus giving duration ranges of over many days.

1. How can I expand the above table to create something like this?

   ```
   id   date   timestampdiff(hour, login_datetime, logout_datetime) as "hourslapsed"


   1   Oct 1               14
   1   Oct 2               24
   1   Oct 3               24
   1   Oct 4               17
   2   Oct 3                1
   2   Oct 4               24  
   2   Oct 5                1
   ```
2. Is expanding the lapsed_table and then calcuating daily avg and total the best way to approach this? Ultimately I want to create something like this:

   ```
   Date    Avg Daily Hours  Total Daily Hours
   ----    ---------------  -----------------
   Oct 1       14             14 
   Oct 2       24             24 
   Oct 3       12.5           25
   Oct 4       20.5           41
   ```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MySQL ? Your datetime values, using double quotes for aliases, does not make it look like mysql

Comment: I'm new to MySQL, so I am unfamiliar with the single/double quote conventions. However, from my understanding MySQL supports both single and double quotes for aliases. The datetime format in my example table were arbitrarily chosen for simplicity's sake.

Comment: you can use a query like `select this and this from table where date between 10 and 20`

Comment: @Rami Far I'm not quite sure what you mean by that?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp see this link for the syntax. By using this query you can get your values between any 2 dates

Comment: @Rami Far Sorry, I'm not understanding how that solves the problem. I'm not trying to get all the values between two date ranges, I'm trying to calcuate the daily avg and sum of the amount of time a user spends on the platform.